# Chrome Plugin image persists after close

Tags: image, google-chrome, plugins, firebreath

I have been developing a media player browser plugin for the past few month using Firebreath, but I do not think this is a Firebreath problem.

Currently I am stuck on this weird problem that occurs when one tries to reload the webpage containing the plugin. The image that was being displayed before the reload will stay stuck on the top of screen. The new reloaded plugin will be alive and well behind it but the old image will stay stuck their on the screen forever. If I scroll or resize the browser or even change URLs the image will stay put, however If I move the browser the image will follow. The image stays after closing a tab, but leaves when closing the window

Here is a screenshot that demonstrates what I am talking about.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ2WH.jpg

( I am a new user so I cant post images )

Has you can see I left my plugin's page and went to the Firebreath website and the image still persists.

This problem happens on both windows and linux, much less frequently on linux, and happens when using both directx and opengl. But only happens on chrome.

Just wondering if you, or anybody else, has any thoughts, suggestions, or insights as to what might be happening. I've tried everything including atrocious hacks and nothing seems to work.

Thank you.

Comment: This is only happening on windows, right? How are you drawing? Normal GDI, directx, opengl?

Comment: Using both Directx or OpenGL cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that you aren't tearing down your directx or opengl context when the DetachedEvent fires. AttachedEvent is the earliest you can set it up, and DetachedEvent is the latest you can leave it running.

Comment: I am calling delete on my context on the detachedEvent. Is this not enough?

Comment: I'm not an opengl or directx expert, so I don't know; however, what you are describing sounds very much like your context isn't being cleaned up properly.

Comment: Yeah I suspected something like that. I'll look into more and let you know if something interesting comes up. Thank you for your time.